# time() not returning daylight savings value

Tags: php, wordpress, timezone

After setting the following I expect time() to return the epoch time for British Summer Time, but instead I get UTC/GMT.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
```

I have values stored in a database adjusted for BST and need to compare the value returned by time(). The system is currently not working as expected as there is an hours difference. Either the time() function needs to return BST time or I need a way to detect if London is in BST so as to add 3600 to the result from time(). Either solution would be welcome.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");

// Wordpress - Getting a value from the DB
$min_deadline = get_post_meta($id,'wdm_deadline_min',true);

$min_signup_check = false;
if (!empty($min_deadline) && time() >= strtotime($min_deadline))
    $min_signup_check = true;
```

Comment: That's just how `time()` works. Use a DateTime object instead

Comment: There seems to be no end to the annoying problems caused from daylight savings time.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII daylight savings time is an outdated concept which pre-dates artifical light. It's only here to cause problems.

Comment: In deed! At least you're using the base 10 metric system, while us Americans are *still* stuck with the wonky imperial system. So much wasted time programming unit/time conversions. You should search for a library instead of rolling your own.

Comment: @apokryfos new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone("Europe/London")) // Gives me UTC/GMT.

Comment: @PeterBushnell you must be doing something wrong because https://eval.in/616198 works for me

Comment: If you're working with dates, times, or timezones, save yourself an extraordinary amount of effort and just grab http://carbon.nesbot.com/.

Comment: There is no such thing as the epoch time for BST. Unix time is _always_ in UTC, so what you want is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Found these two methods below and am now using getoffset to return the difference if any between GMT and BST.

```
function getOffset($tzId, $time = null) {
    if($time == null){
        $time = gmdate('U');
    }

    $tz = new DateTimeZone($tzId);

    $transition = $tz->getTransitions($time);

    return $transition[0]['offset'];
}

function getDST($tzId, $time = null) {
    if($time == null){
        $time = gmdate('U');
    }

    $tz = new DateTimeZone($tzId);

    $transition = $tz->getTransitions($time);

    return $transition[0]['isdst'];
}
```